# I wonder which is faster between list.contains() and set.contains() in scala

Tags: scala, collections

I have a very large collection which contains more than a million **String** elements. It is very often to check whether a coming **String** is in this collection or not.

I wonder which collection is better to use, **List** or **Set**? And why?

Comment: I think it's basic data structures question. You can use a `Set` or a bloom filter (if you're fine with false positives). You can also find the performance characteristics [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Set* will be more fast, since it could be based on tree structure (complexity will be something like **O(height of the tree)** or using hashes (complexity will be near **O(const)**) , on the other size contains for *List* will have complexity **O(n)**, where *n* - size of the list

So Set should be faster when we talk about large calls of *contains()*

Comment: Thx. I find that on my program `Set.contains()` is 30 times faster than `List.contains()`. Terrible.

Comment: Unless your set is a `ListSet`, in which case the performance will be identical.

Comment: @ConnorDoyle, agree. Just don't know about this weird collection :)